# covert multidimensional array to ul li

Tags: php

i have follow array

```
$array = array(
        array("title" => "soup", 
            array(
                "name" => "miso soup",
                "description" => "popular japanese soup",
                "price" => "7.00","8.00",
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "seafood soup",
                "description" => "very delicious soup",
                "price" => "10.00","18.00",
                ),
        ),
        array("title" => "rice", 
            array(
                "name" => "miso soup",
                "description" => "popular japanese soup",
                "price" => "7.00","8.00",
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "seafood soup",
                "description" => "very delicious soup",
                "price" => "10.00","18.00",
            ),
        )
    );
```

My end goal is to create list like

```
    <h1>soup</h1>
<ul>
    <li>miso soup <p>popular japanese soup</p><span>7.00<span><span>8.00</span></li>
    <li>seafood soup <p>very delicious soup</p><span>10.00</span><span>18.00</span></li>
</ul>
<h1>rice</h1>
<ul>
    <li>miso soup <p>popular japanese soup</p><span>7.00<span><span>8.00</span></li>
    <li>seafood soup <p>very delicious soup</p><span>10.00</span><span>18.00</span></li>
</ul>
```

i try to put for loop inside foreach, be the result came out with duplicate li.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us your best attempt. You learn when you try, not when you copy-paste some other people's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the design of your array, for at the top array there will be the entries "title", "0" and "1" which make it more difficult. Also, the syntax does not make what you want with the prices. Make it like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "title" => "soup",
        "data" => array(
            array(
                "name" => "miso soup",
                "description" => "popular japanese soup",
                "price" => array("7.00","8.00"),
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "seafood soup",
                "description" => "very delicious soup",
                "price" => array("10.00","18.00"),
            )
        ),
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "rice", 
        "data" => array(
            array(
                "name" => "miso soup",
                "description" => "popular japanese soup",
                "price" => array("7.00","8.00"),
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "seafood soup",
                "description" => "very delicious soup",
                "price" => array("10.00","18.00"),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Finally, you can create your output like this:

```
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    echo "<h1>".$entry['title']."</h1>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($entry['data'] as $data) {
        echo "<li>".$data['name']." <p>".$data['description']."</p>";
        foreach ($data['price'] as $price) {
            echo "<span>".$price."</span>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: thank u very much florian, sorry that i didn't see that u modify the array, now it's working , thank u again ^^

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will helps

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    echo '<h1>'.$row['title'].'</h1>';
    unset($row['title']);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($row as $list) {
        echo '<li>'.$list['name'].'<p>'.$list['description'].'</p><span>'.$list['price'].'</span><span>'.$list[0].'</span></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
foreach($array as $item){
    echo "<h1>".$item['title']."</h1>";
    echo "<ul>";
    for($i=0;$i<count($item)-1;$i++)
    {
        $des=$item[$i];
        echo "<li>".$des['name'];           
        echo "<p>".$des['description']."</p>";
        echo "<p>".$des['price']."</p>";            
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";   
}
```